# How to redirect from browser to Metamask or similar app like trustwallet on android?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3-providers

I have a website that detects metamask and connects with it on pc, but on the android mobile app browser when I open my website it doesn't show some functions as it needs to be connected with BSC, So is there any option like when user open website and visit that particular page so app suggestion should pop-up like if we open any downloaded image from chrome shows app suggestion (in which app you would like to open - so similar in this case but this time website should directly open in metamask or trust wallet browser.

Answer (score 3):

If your app is on React, you can use [react-open-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-open-app) to enable deep links. If not, you can still borrow [its implementation](https://github.com/enzoferey/react-open-app/blob/master/lib/index.js) to do it yourself as it's MIT licensed.

Also, [Metamask Deeplinks](https://metamask.github.io/metamask-deeplinks/#) is a good tool to get your deeplinks.

Comment: You should use [WalletConnect mobile linking](https://docs.walletconnect.org/mobile-linking) for most of these use cases.

Comment: spoiler: WalletConnect's metamask integration is very unreliable